# Bot is mixing up prompts from concurrent users

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm having an issue where multiple users concurrently accessing the same dialog are having their prompt values mixed up. The dialog in question is an Order Status dialog where, among other things, the order number is prompted. I am seeing cases where User 1 queries Order A, User 2 queries Order B (at nearly the same time) and then both users receive information for Order B.

This is a complex dialog and sharing the complete code wouldn't be helpful, but here are a few points I feel may be relevant:

- I am using `this.queryData = {}` in the constructor to initiate an object to hold all of the order query parameters I am prompting for, including order number.

  - I thought perhaps this object was getting overridden by the second user, but I'm also setting the user and conversation state here, as I do in every dialog, so I'm not sure that's it. I have always assumed each instance of this dialog is created uniquely for each user.
- I am using a simple text prompt:

```js
return await step.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, {
    prompt: `Please provide your ${step.values.orderTypeText} number.`,
    retryPrompt: `Please enter a valid ${step.values.orderTypeText} number.`,
});
```

- And then in the next step assigning to the queryData object as `this.queryData.orderNumber = step.result.trim().split(" ").splice(-1)[0];`

And that's really it, unless there is some way that it's not the prompt value but the entire message that is getting send to the wrong user (but that seems quite unlikely, plus it is going to both users in this example).

I have considered instead of using `this.queryData` to store the information in `conversationState`, but I don't want to redo the code unless I can confirm this is an issue with the implementation I have used, specifically `this.queryData` rather than some other issue.

For reference, here is the class definition, down to the end of the constructor:

```js
class viewOrderDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(dialogId, userDialogStateAccessor, userState, appInsightsClient, dialogState, conversationState) {
        super(dialogId);

        this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CRITERIA_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(TEXT_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(LINE_PROMPT, this.validateLineNumber));
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(EMAIL_PROMPT,this.validateEmail));
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(ZIP_PROMPT,this.validateZip));
        this.addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.requestOrderNumber.bind(this),
            this.selectOrderType.bind(this), // This is being bypassed by current Filtration store implementation
            this.selectSearchCriteria.bind(this),
            this.getQueryData.bind(this),
            this.confirmBillingZip.bind(this),
            this.confirmBillingEmail.bind(this),
            this.displayLineStatus.bind(this),
            this.getEmailAddress.bind(this),
            this.setFollowUp.bind(this),
            this.loopStep.bind(this)
        ]));

        this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;

        this.queryData = {};

        // State accessors
        this.userDialogStateAccessor = userDialogStateAccessor;
        this.userState = userState;
        this.dialogState = dialogState;
        this.conversationState = conversationState;

        this.appInsightsClient = appInsightsClient;

        this.addDialog(new PaginateDialog(PAGINATE_DIALOG, this.userDialogStateAccessor, userState, this.appInsightsClient));

        // Luis Recognizer
        this.luisRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer({
            applicationId: process.env.LuisAppId,
            endpointKey: process.env.LuisAPIKey,
            endpoint: `https://${ process.env.LuisAPIHostName }`
        }, {
            includeAllIntents: true,
            includeInstanceData: true,
            spellCheck: true,
            bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey: process.env.bingAPIKey
        }, true);

    } // End constructor
```

Comment: Could you provide us more of your code please. For example, when referencing `this.queryData`, what is `this` in this case? A class? A function? An arrow function? Could it be that `this` is referencing the global context?

Comment: It's a class for the viewOrderDialog waterfall dialog. I'll add the full constructor including class definition above.

Comment: Is this happening with all prompts, some prompts, or specifically this prompt? Are you seeing any crossover between other activities, for instance, input by user B is causing the bot to respond to user A?

Comment: Also, what client(s) is your bot being accessed thru? If using DirectLine (e.g. Web Chat), check that the user Id generated with the token is unique enough. If there is a chance the user Id is getting duplicated and used by multiple users, this can result in conversations getting crossed. A related consideration is if you are using load balancing in the app service where a new instance is created. This could be causing the user Id to get re-used.

Comment: I'll say "all prompts". It has happened with at least 3 different prompts across two dialogs. I'm using DirectLine and I don't think there's any way the user ID could be duplicated. It is the timestamp in ms + a 9 digit random number. Not using load balancing.

Comment: @StevenKanberg my intuition says that this.queryData is being used globally across all users of the dialog. But then again that doesn't make sense because a new dialog is created every time the main bot.js file runs (for each new user). And also, this is the suggested way to set up user and conversation state in the dialog (setting as `this.whatever` in the constructor) and to my knowledge there's no crossing of state values. I'm not opposed to storing the query data in conversation state, but I'd rather not make that change unless its required.

Comment: @billoverton, I gave this some more thought and I think you are right in that `this.queryData` is used globally. I tested to be sure and every component dialog is loaded when the bot starts up. What makes a dialog unique from one user to another I believe is the metadata passed into the dialog's processes. With `this.queryData`, I think the last value used is somehow being persisted. Maybe it's always going with the last value in the object? Are you able to improve the filter logic that is used to pull data from `this.queryData`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, filter logic. I have made the assumption this variable is only being filled by the current instance of the dialog. But the behavior I am seeing seems to imply this is not true. I have even tried reinitializing `this.queryData` right before I use it, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. If this is what is causing the issue, what alternative should I be using? I suppose I might be able to store the info in `step.values` instead of `this.queryData`, but my dialog has a loop. I think `step.values` will be cleared on the loop, but those values shouldn't persist.

Comment: So I was concerned about step.values holding its data through the loop, but the opposite turned out to be the problem. I was depending on certain values being retained in `this.queryData` for my "loop branch" of the dialog, the fact that those were retained are probably proof that globally all dialogs are updating the same variables. I am making some modifications to pass the values I need to retain through the options parameter in `beginDialog()`, where I can reset in `step.values` in the loop branch (I suppose I could use the options to maintain this throughout but I'm not sure I like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arie Rodrigues got me going in the right direction but the solution was not quite correct. Bot Framework does in fact seem to be using a single instance of the dialog, with it being controlled by the conversation/dialog state. So the `this.queryData` object defined in the constructor was actually being shared by all dialogs. With the right timing, prompt inputs were crossing from one user's dialog to the other.

This could be solved with any method to save these values non-globally. Conversation state would be a good one, but I didn't need or want to save the values for the duration of the conversation nor mess with retrieving and saving the state every step. Instead, I used `step.values` in place of `this.queryData`. My code had actually relied on some values of `this.queryData` being persisted when the dialog was looped at a certain step via `replaceDialog()`, so I had to make sure to pass those in the options of that method. This seems to have fixed the issue, as I had 4 testers hitting the same dialogs at the same time with different prompt values without issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm used to work with Botframework with .net, but i think the overall mechanism will not differ too much from the node.

In the .net implementation of BotBuilder, like you said, all the dialogs instances are stored in a single instance on the application start to avoid a load of dialog instances running with almost the same data.

To avoid mix information between dialogs instances, you have some options:

- Use state management to store contextual data like conversationData, for example, for conversation wide domain information and share data between all the dialogs;
- Or you can store dialog domain information with the `stepContext.options` and it will be recoverable in any step while the dialog stays in the stack (before you hit the final step, call `endDialog` or `replaceDialog`).

Here some information on how to store data:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript

Comment: I am familiar with conversation state variable but prefer not to use it for various reasons. I've used `stepContext._info.options`, which is passed in as the option parameter of `beginDialog()`. I suppose that would work but when I loop/replace dialogs I usually pass back the options, so dealing with making sure the variables I set in that object were reinitialized would be a pain. I have implemented a similar approach with `step.values` however. I think it is the same concept. I'm in testing now, will let you know how it works out.